# Eloquent save method associates the relation to the Model instance?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I would like to know if after:

```
$post = Post::find(1);
$author = new Author($someData);
$post->author()->save($author);
```

the following code is lazy loading the author?

```
$authorName = $post->author->name;
```

To clarify Post an Author have a OneToOne relation.

If I use:

```
dump($post);
```

the output does not contain the author and shows this:

```
#relations: []
```

Same result using $post->author()->createMany() method

So I want to be sure it does not make an extra query to load the author since I have it in memory already.

laravel/framework: 5.4.*

Comment: You will need to load the relationship after saving it `$post->load('author');`. But if you do `$authorName = $post->author->name;`, yes, it' lazy load, but relationship attributes are lazy loaded the first time they are accessed. Once loaded, they are not automatically refreshed with records that are added or removed from the relationship.

Comment: There is a way to accomplish that with only 2 queries? One to save the Post and another and another to save the Author. And then access $post->author->name without fetch the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this if you really want to. You can use `setRelation`.

```php
$post = Post::find(1);

$author = Author::create($someDataWithPostId); // save the author instance to the database.

$post->setRelation('author', $author); // set relation method will set the author as author relation.
```

Now when you access `$authorName = $post->author->name;` it will not load from the database since we have already set the author relation to the data to the post.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try Eager Loading by with function 
example

```
$post= Model::with('author')->find(id);
```

then let your one To One Relational method Name is "author" in post model
you can find it by  `dd($post->author->name)`

Comment: As you can see in the question the Post model instance is been created. I if use $post= Model::with('author')->find(id); it will query the database needlessly.